# Matching everything behind a dot (TLDs)

Tags: regex

I am trying to match everything behind a dot in multiple lines, such as TLDs in urls or folders in package declarations.

This only works for the last line:

```
[^\.]([^.]*)$
```

see http://www.regexr.com/3auec

How can I find matches in each line?

Expected output:

```
com!
uk
uk/
html?q=bar
hyphenated_name
_123name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add add global and multiline flags

```
/[^\.]([^.]*)$/gm
```

http://regexr.com/3auei

Comment: This works in the referenced online editor, but not in Notepad++. Is /gm a standard expression? In Notepad++ it can just be left out, /[^\.]([^.]*)$ works fine

Comment: they are fairly well used regex flags. I have not used notepad++, so I can't comment on that.  I would suggest you include the fact that you are using notepad++ in your question next time (I am sure there is a tag for it).